# Implement htaccess rewrite rules using wordpress methods

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to implement the following rewrite rules of htaccess using word press rewrite rules. WP rewrite should be the way to go but not sure how a scenario like this can be implemented, please advise.

```
RewriteRule ^authorbio/?$ /mainblog/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^authorbio/([^/]+/.+)$ $1 [NC,L,R]
```

My condition should be in such a way that if in the url after authorbio ONLY ONE WORD is found then leave it as it is. for all remaining conditions it should remove authorbio/

The conditions 2 & 3 in below example are generic and can be done easily but it should be done along with condition#1 in example

Example:

```
THIS SHOULD REMAIN AS IT IS:

/mainblog/authorbio/authorname

SHOULD BE CHANGED TO

/mainblog/authorbio/authorname

WHERE AS THIS SHOULD REMOVE AUTHORBIO FROM THE URL

/mainblog/authorbio/someblog/blogarticle

SHOULD BE CHANGED TO

/mainblog/someblog/blogarticle

Also THIS SHOULD REMOVE AUTHORBIO FROM THE URL

/mainblog/authorbio/

SHOULD BE CHANGED TO

/mainblog
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @howlin added more information to my question please check